# Bootstrap-5 navbar button from left to right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I want to change this `bootstrap5` navbar buttons from left side to a right side, but I don't know how to do that using `css` or `bootstrap5`, guys how can I do this?

My Code:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
    rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" 
    crossorigin="anonymous">

 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <div class="container">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <h1>Pondadb</h1>
          </a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
        
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
              <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="btn btn-primary mx-lg-2 mx-0 my-lg-0 my-2" href="#">About</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="btn btn-primary mx-lg-2 mx-0 my-lg-0 my-2" href="#">Contact</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="btn btn-primary mx-lg-2 mx-0 my-lg-0 my-2" href="#">Login</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="btn btn-primary mx-lg-2 mx-0 my-lg-0 my-2" href="#">Singn-Up</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `.mr-auto` which is Bootstrap 4's version of `margin-right: auto;`. This does not work in B5 and the correct class would be `.me-auto`.

However, you don't want `margin-right: auto;`, you want `margin-left: auto;` to push the elements to the right. In B5, you should use `ms-auto`.

[Spacing · Bootstrap v5.3](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/utilities/spacing/)

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
      <h1>Pondadb</h1>
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="btn btn-primary mx-lg-2 mx-0 my-lg-0 my-2" href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="btn btn-primary mx-lg-2 mx-0 my-lg-0 my-2" href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="btn btn-primary mx-lg-2 mx-0 my-lg-0 my-2" href="#">Login</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="btn btn-primary mx-lg-2 mx-0 my-lg-0 my-2" href="#">Singn-Up</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think changing of "mr-auto" in  into "ml-auto" should help. It is bootstrap form of margin-right: auto, so it means that it is positioned at right. If I undertand you right, you want it to be on right side, so change it to margin-left: auto = ml-auto.

Comment: it does not work: `class="navbar-nav ml-auto"`